# Listening for events on specific HTML elements

Tags: angular

I am trying to figure out how to listen for specific event on a specific element in angular2.

HTML

```
<div id="hello-world">
    Just a random message
</div>
```

in javascript i have this implemented as:

```
document.getElementById("hello-world").addEventListener("mousewheel", (e) => {
console.info(e);
});
```

Not sure what the proper way to implement this in Angular2, hoping someone would have a answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this:

**Directives**

You can create a directive which will be applied to your webcomponent/component and then, you will be able to react to event with @HostListener. Here is an example:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[highlight]'
})

class HighlightDirective {
    constructor(private _element: ElementRef) {
    }

    @HostListener('click') onClick() {
        this.highlightConfig = {
            color: 'green'
        };

        this._element.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor =
            this._element.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor ? null : this.highlightConfig.color;
    }

}
```

and then apply this to the component:

```
<div highlight>here</div>
```

This example will change the background-color of the div when the user click. As you can see, @HostListener('click') say "Ok guys, i'll react and apply the function bellow everytime a user click on the component I am applied on"

For mousewheel, the hostlistener is:

```
@HostListener('mousewheel', ['$event']) onMouseWheelChrome(event: any) {
    // my code
}
```

**Events**

You also have defaults/custom events which you can apply on your components:

```
<div (click)="myFunc()">Here</div>
```

Comment: what about without using directive?

Comment: Yep, as I said, you can simply use the events. For wheel, you have "(wheel)='myFunc()'".