# How to controll the scrolling of a div?

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll, angular6

In my Angular 6 project I have a material dialog popup. This dialog displays a list of City names. The list has a scroll bar and works fine.

Now I need to make the list respond to the arrow up and down and have the highlighted row move with the key press, I did this with the host listener.

```
@HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  console.log(event);

  if (event.keyCode === 40) {
    this.selectedIndex++;
  }

  if (event.keyCode === 38) {
    this.selectedIndex--;
  }
}
```

The problem I am having is that each click also moves the scroll bar, but they are not in sync. After a few clicks the highlighted row moves past the visible scroll area.

How can I keep the highlighted row within the visible viewing area of the scroll area?

Is there a way to control how far the scroll moves to match the row height of my rows?

Thanks

Comment: Use window.scrollBy() to move the equivalent of the height (either up or down)

Comment: How do I target the scroll inside the mat-dialog-content?

Comment: You can try by creating a directive and attaching that to your dialog-content tag.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43489632/listening-for-events-on-specific-html-elements

Answer (score 0):

I created a variable for the selectedIndex, purely for illustration purposes.

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})


export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  selectedIndex:number =0;



@HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  console.log(event);

  if (event.keyCode === 40) {
    this.selectedIndex++;
    window.scrollBy(0,window.scrollY+40)
    console.log(window.scrollY, this.selectedIndex)
  }

  if (event.keyCode === 38) {
    this.selectedIndex--;
    window.scrollBy(0,window.scrollY-40)
  }
}

}
```

Comment: The scroll does not seem to effect the scroll bar in the Material dialog.